# Tile grid world creation trouble

Tags: java, loops, graphics, bufferedimage, tiles

I'm shooting an idea here and have come across a few problems. Firstly I have a class with a method for creating new worlds.

The 2D tiled world gets created like this:

```
for(int y = 0; y < WORLDSIZE; y++){
    for(int x = 0; x < WORLDSIZE; x++){
        tiles.add(new Tile(Sprite.blanktile, x*32, y*32));
    }
}
```

This creates and predefines the entire worlds tile positions and gives them all a blank tile sprite. It's only run once at start. The class where this gets processed is where the problem starts.

Here the tiles are iterated through and skips all tiles that are not on the screen. The `xoff` and `yoff` are up, down, left, right offsets for moving the screen around. I'm a bit worried about editing the actual grid locations. I'm sure I will be able to account for that when needed.

This is the general idea.

```
while(true){
    for(int i = 0; i < world.tiles.size(); i++){
        world.tiles.get(i).x += xoff;
        world.tiles.get(i).y += yoff;

        if(world.tiles.get(i).y + yoff > GameWindow.HEIGHT || world.tiles.get(i).y + yoff < -64 || world.tiles.get(i).x + xoff > GameWindow.WIDTH || world.tiles.get(i).x + xoff < -64){
            continue;
        }else
            render.setTilePixel(world.tiles.get(i).sprite, world.tiles.get(i).x, world.tiles.get(i).y);
    }

    window.draw(render.visualization());
}
```

It sets each tiles pixels every time it updates. Which is making it quite slow for something that should be less. The way it sets the pixels is like this:

```
public void setTilePixel(Sprite sprite, int x, int y){
    int xa, ya;
    for(int hrzt = 0; hrzt < sprite.SIZE; hrzt++){
        for(int vtc = 0; vtc < sprite.SIZE; vtc++){
            xa =  (hrzt + x);
            ya =  (vtc + y);
            if(xa < width && xa > -1){
                if (xa + ya * width < width*height && xa + ya * width > 0){
                    if(sprite.pixels[hrzt + vtc * sprite.SIZE] != 0xff000000 && sprite.pixels[hrzt + vtc * sprite.SIZE] != 0){
                        visualizer.pixels[xa + ya * width] = sprite.pixels[hrzt + vtc * sprite.SIZE];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The last operations send the new image data to the window to be drawn to the screen.
`window.draw(render.visualization());`

The issue here is that it is taking a long time each cycle. I've tried a few other ways but its taking a long time, like a whole week. So, I've come here. The more tiles I'm processing causes it to get a lot slower. I'm looking for a new way. Possibly where it does everything in the same section of for loops cutting the reiteration down?

Hope I've got enough up. Let me know what else I should add. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of small suggestions:

Firstly, you are ultimately rendering these to a screen, I assume. Can you work out where the tiles are in relation to what will be displayed, and skip the ones that are not going to be rendered? This should cut down your calculation volume significantly.

Secondly, in your setTilePixel method, you loop through the full range of hrzt and vtc values, and then have some checks to see whether to do action or not. You could do something like this, change:

```
for(int hrzt = 0; hrzt < sprite.SIZE; hrzt++){
    for(int vtc = 0; vtc < sprite.SIZE; vtc++){
        xa =  (hrzt + x);
        ya =  (vtc + y);
        if(xa < width && xa > -1){
            if (xa + ya * width < width*height && xa + ya * width > 0){
            // ***
            }
        }
    }
}
```

to:

```
int maxValidHrzt = width-x;
int minValidHrzt = -1;
int maxValidVtc = etc...
int minValidVtc = etc...
for(int hrzt = minValidHrzt; hrzt < maxValidHrzt; hrzt++){
    for(int vtc = minValidVtc; vtc < maxValidVtc; vtc++){
        // ***
    }
}
```